# How do I get config paramerters from my web.xml in Jersey?

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, jetty

I have been trying to get parameters from my `web.xml` file from within my Jakarta JAX-RS resource. My web.xml is as follows:

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>terrible.package.name</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>max-customers-size</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

In my test setup, I am running my web app with Jetty:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext("target/the-finished-servlet.war", "/");
    server.setHandler(ctx);
    server.start();
}
```

And I have the following user resource defined using jakarta:

```java
@Path("user")
public class UserResource {

    ServletContext context;
    
    @Context
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println("setting to: " + context);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getListOfAllUsers(final @Context HttpHeaders hdrs) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(context.getInitParameter("max-customers-size"));
        return Response.ok("{}").build();
    }

}
```

The context is always `null`, which makes absolutely no sense. The `setServletContext` method is called, and the parameter is `null`. I've tried using `@Context` on a constructor parameter, I've tried it on my context field, and I've tried it in the `getListOfAllUsers` method. None of them work.

I just want to configure my servlet (for MySQL database path and user, in this example I'm testing with `max-customers-size`, which doesn't matter though, because my context is `null` either way). Is there an easier way to get custom config data into my servlet? I want the user of my resulting `war` file to be able to supply things like the database port. Why isn't ServletContext working, and if there is an easier way to make my servlet configurable, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a database (DataSource) for Servlet is configured via JNDI (the definition exists on the server JNDI context, and the webapp JNDI context contains a hardcoded reference to the server level location)

Your server level will typically have an XML that defines the `DataSource` as a `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource` against the server level context.

And your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` contains the `<resource-ref>` back to that server level location.

Your code then uses the `InitialContext` on JNDI to access this already defined `DataSource`.

This has the added bonus that the datasource can be any JDBC compatible implementation, and even include complex configurations like a Connection pool implementation (eg: c3p0) in front of your JDBC DataSource.

For unit testing, you'll set it up like this ...
[JNDI Lookup Failing For Embedded Jetty Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729215/jndi-lookup-failing-for-embedded-jetty-server)

For standard webapp deployment in a standalone Jetty container, you'll set it up like this ...
[Declaring JNDI Resources](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/operations-guide/index.html#og-declaring-resources)